# Standard water heater outside the house?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, outdoor

A guest house built with one bedroom also had a nice sized portion left unfinished for storage and freezer space. We have decided to finish this area, making a second bedroom.

Currently the 50 gal water heater is installed in this space. 
The home is total electric no gas.
We don’t want an electric tankless water heater because of the expensive upgrades to the electrical system.

I have seen the little [water heater enclosures](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Holdrite-24-in-Water-Heater-Enclosure-QS-E24/206035055) sold at big box stores.
I am considering moving the 50gal tank heater outside into one of these.
We are in South Carolina with pretty mild winters.
What drawbacks are there to this type installation and what considerations should be taken to insure that I don’t have problems with such a project?

Comment: I take it there is absolutely nowhere inside the guest house a tank can live?  Also, does this guest house have a full kitchen and laundry associated with it, just a kitchen (no laundry), or neither?

Comment: Also, does the guest house have an attic? Is this attic vented (outside space) with insulation at the ceiling plane, or is the roof deck itself insulated instead?

Comment: How is the guest house heated even?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  house has electric heat pump. There is a laundry room 1 bathroom and kitchen.  Also has an attic not much height however. I’m a bit leery of attic installed water heater.

Comment: Is the heat pump a split system type with a full air handler in the house, or a mini-split type (with ductless or miniduct heads)?

Comment: Also, is there space in the laundry room for a water heater tank?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel heat pump is not split air handler and plenum are outside too.  Laundry room is combined into bathroom so no space there.

Answer (score 1):

I live in Georgia and we have similar weather in the winter. You shouldn't have an issue using that enclosure. However, I would insulate this very well. You never know when we could get another winter superstorm like we experienced in 1993.

Comment: The only thing you don't know is the date.

Comment: The storm date? March 15, 1993?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_Storm_of_the_Century

Comment: i meant the *next* one.   But good point, that one's date was unknown in 1990.

Comment: We rarely get big storms in the south. I recall a few. I was merely trying to emphasize the need for insulation.